# cascading deletes with fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a mapping as follows:

```
public class InvoiceDetailMapping : ClassMap<InvoiceDetail>
{
    public InvoiceDetailMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.DetailId)
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();

        Map(x => x.Account);
        Map(x => x.Credit);
        Map(x => x.Debit);
        Map(x => x.PayType);
        Map(x => x.RowNumber);

        References<InvoiceItem>(x => x.Invoice, "InvoiceItemId")
            .Cascade.All();

    }
}

public class InvoiceItemMapping : ClassMap<InvoiceItem>
{
    public InvoiceItemMapping()
    {
        Id(x => x.RecordId)
            .GeneratedBy.Guid();

        Map(x => x.BatchId);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Map(x => x.DocumentDate);
        Map(x => x.DocumentId);
        Map(x => x.DocumentType);
        Map(x => x.FileId);
        Map(x => x.FileName);
        Map(x => x.InvoiceAmount);
        Map(x => x.LocationCode);
        Map(x => x.PayDate);
        Map(x => x.PaymentTerms);
        Map(x => x.PayNumber);
        Map(x => x.PurchaseAmount);
        Map(x => x.PurchaseInvoiceAmount);
        Map(x => x.InvoiceId);
        Map(x => x.Submittable);
        Map(x => x.SubmittedBy);
        Map(x => x.SubmittedTimeStamp);
        Map(x => x.TaxForm1099Amount);
        Map(x => x.TroubleClass);
        Map(x => x.VendorDocNumber);
        Map(x => x.VendorId);
        Map(x => x.PersistedTimeStamp)
            .CustomType<UtcDateTimeType>()
            .Generated.Insert();

        HasMany<InvoiceDetail>(x => x.InvoiceDetails)
            .Inverse()
            .Cascade.All()
            .KeyColumn("InvoiceItemId");
    }
}
```

... but when I apply this to my PostgreSQL database, it creates the following SQL for the InvoiceDetail:

```
CREATE TABLE "InvoiceDetail"
(
  detailid uuid NOT NULL,
  account character varying(255),
  credit numeric(19,5),
  debit numeric(19,5),
  paytype integer,
  rownumber integer,
  invoiceitemid uuid,
  CONSTRAINT "InvoiceDetail_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (detailid ),
  CONSTRAINT fkd8588014e9009e93 FOREIGN KEY (invoiceitemid)
      REFERENCES "InvoiceItem" (recordid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Note the `ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION` line.  I would have thought the `Cascade.All()` directive would create a `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE` DDL.  What did I do incorrectly or incompletely?

Comment: The mapping looks correct. Did you test your code? I think that NHibernate does not support cascaded deletes when they're executed directly on the database, but handles the cascades itself by sending additional SQL commands.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte What code is there to test?  It compiles, the entities are created using NHibernate, the PersistenceSpecification tests pass, that all works... it just seems that the foreign keys would be designed to support cascading deletes.  It *has* to be a considerably more expensive operation to have the NHibernate subsystem explicitly delete dependent records.

Comment: But for me, it looks like that's how NHibernate works. It's the same on our projects that use SQLServer or MySQL, both DB support ON DELETE on foreign key constraints, but NHibernate does not use them and deletes the referenced rows itself.

Comment: Hmm.  So this is by design then.  Well that's lame.  Write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, I was wrong. NHibernate can support it, if the Dialect.SupportsCascadeDelete=true and the ForeignKey mapping has CascadeDeleteEnabled=true. We also use fluent, and it looks like this is a bug in FluentNHibernate. Can you write the mapping files to a temp directory and add the mappings here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NH supports many different RDBMS and already for a long time hence the default is to do it in code. FNH on the other hand startet to implement the most common features which this one is not. And there was still no one filing an issue to support this NH feature. Also it is difficult to say because in the mapping the Dialect is not known hence it can not know if the feature is even supported.